# Can anyone tell me why my buttons are not displaying content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm making a custom video player with HTML/JS, however I've run into quite a weird issue. I have two buttons that are just not displaying their content, specifically the Fast Forward and Rewind button. I've tried everything, but cannot get them to display content within the CSS. Any idea why they're not displaying?

```
   #ff {
     content: url("https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/fast-forward.png");
   }
   #rw {
     content: url("https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rewind.png");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9sqdvg2n/#

Thanks!

Comment: because `content` is used for ::after or ::before pseudo-elements - by the way, your ff and rw buttons are the wrong way around (if you follow decades of convention for such things)

Comment: @JaromandaX well that appears to have been the answer. Thank you!

Comment: The issue is taht you are using <button>. I don't know why UAs do not replace these with the <image> but if your elements were something else, or if you were targetting a child element in these buttons, that [would work](https://jsfiddle.net/s4mLfr9o/). Don't have time to read more deeply the specs and issues to find the why...

Answer (score 0):

> Note: the content property should work according to all documentation, however it seems the `<button>` element resists this CSS3 content property!
>
> If you were to use a `<span>` or a `<div>` or almost any other element (not `<input>` either as far as I can tell), then your original CSS would do exactly what you wanted it to do in modern browsers

---

css *content* property is used only for pseudo-elements ::after and ::before (and others like ::marker?) - as above `content` *should* also work as you've used it)

```
#ff::after {
  content: url("https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/fast-forward.png");
}
#rw::after {
  content: url("https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rewind.png");
```

Should fix this

Comment: hum [not really](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#Element_replacement), in [css-content-3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#content-property) it applies to all elements. Chrome had support since v28 and FF added it in v63 (with images at least).

Comment: well I'll be damned - need to keep up with these things I guess - so I wonder why the OP's code is wrong?

Comment: Seems `<button>` can't get replaced. Weirdly enough though I didn't found anything pointing to this behavior, but all UAs are acting the same... (I didn't spent too much time digging though, I may very well have missed it)

Comment: yes, I just checked, and button does seem to resist being changed!

Comment: Found [that](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215083#c50). It's FF implementation issue, and they just say they saw Chrome doesn't allow it on <button> and <iframe>.

Comment: *It's FF implementation issue* and Chrome, you even say FF does exactly what Chrome does :p

Comment: No I mean the link I gave to mozilla's bugzilla is the issue tracking the implementation of content for elements.

Comment: @Kaiido - I understand :p

Comment: Somehow this works: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pqxhnufs !

Comment: @Abhitalks - you can't see the difference? you're replacing the content of an `<img>` not a `<button>`

Comment: Exactly, that is what I was pointing out. It works on child elements of a button but not  on the button itself. However, it doesn't work on arbitrary text content though - https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pqxhnufs/11/ ! (which complies with the specs - "*and possibly some associated 'alt text'*")

Answer (score 0):

The CSS *[content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)* property only applies to the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements. An example provided by the MDN docs:

```css
q {
  color: blue;
}

q::before {
  content: open-quote;
}

q::after {
  content: close-quote;
}

h1::before  {
  content: "Chapter ";  /* The trailing space creates separation
                           between the added content and the
                           rest of the content */
}
```

```html
<h1>5</h1>
<p>According to Sir Tim Berners-Lee,
  <q cite="http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/FAQ.html#Internet">I was
    lucky enough to invent the Web at the time when the Internet
    already existed - and had for a decade and a half.</q>
  We must understand that there is nothing fundamentally wrong
  with building on the contributions of others.
</p>

<h1>6</h1>
<p>According to the Mozilla Manifesto,
  <q cite="http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/manifesto/">Individuals
    must have the ability to shape the Internet and
    their own experiences on the Internet.</q>
  Therefore, we can infer that contributing to the open web
  can protect our own individual experiences on it.
</p>
```

The `::before` pseudo-element places the content before the specified element (`p::before`) .

The `::after` pseudo-element places the content after the specified element.

Comment: If you scroll down just a bit, you'll see [an other example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#Element_replacement) which looks more like what OP is doing.

Comment: @Kaiido on the MDN page I linked where it says "Applies to", only the `::before` and `::after` elements are mentioned. You are right though.